How to keep a react three fiber canvas from scaling an object when resizing browser and always render object the same size?
I am using react fiber in one of our projects but the issue I am facing is that the GLB object gets scaled when resizing the browser or is adjusted depending on the browser's size. For example: MS Edge has less page real-estate than chrome, so it renders smaller already on page load. The model is sticky, overlaying content, for animation purposes.
I have no idea how to fix this actually. Could someone maybe help me out with the math or is there another Drei helper I could use? All help would be appreciated!
So it would alway need to be an exact size, regardless of the canvas size.
Code-wise isn't much to go on but
<div
    ref={parentRef}
    className="max-w-container pointer-events-none sticky bottom-0 left-0 top-0 z-10 mx-auto -mb-[120px] hidden h-screen w-full lg:block [&>*]:!pointer-events-none"
  >
    <Canvas
      flat
      dpr={[1, 1.5]}
      gl={{
        preserveDrawingBuffer: true,
        toneMappingExposure: 1,
        outputEncoding: THREE.sRGBEncoding,
      }}
    >
      <ambientLight ref={light} color={0xffffff} intensity={0.3} />
      <Environment
        files={`${
          process.env['NEXT_PUBLIC_ASSET_PREFIX'] ?? ''
        }/pizzo_pernice_puresky_2k.hdr`}
      />
      <Element
        ref={meshRef as React.RefObject<Group<Object3DEventMap>>}
        position={position()}
        rotation={rotation()}
        scale={scale()}
        stateTextureURI={textureURI}
        onLoad={() => setIsLoaded(true)}
      />
    </Canvas>
  </div>


I hope it's not too late, but I just had the same issue and i solved it like this
import { useAspect} from "@react-three/drei";
import { useThree } from "@react-three/fiber";


export const Component = () => {
  const { size } = useThree();

  const getScale = () => {
    if (size.width < size.height) {
      return useAspect(size.width, size.height, 4)[0];
    } else {
      return useAspect(size.width, size.height, 4)[1];
    }
  };

  return (
      <mesh scale={getScale()} />
  );
};


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
